# Why does web3 say the transaction hasn't been mined in 750 seconds when the blockchain transaction says it was mined in 1:30 seconds

Tags: web3js, nodejs, mainnet

We keep getting an error from our node application with the following error:

**Transaction was not mined within 750 seconds, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!**

I've traced the error back and the transactions are being mined in around a minute most times. I was going to increase the gas price but I don't feel it's going to help.

Some info:

- The transaction is going through Infura with Web3 and it's intermittent.
- The transaction is interacting with a smart contract function on the Etherum mainnet.
- The transaction completed in 1 minute 30 seconds
- Gas limit: 300,000
- Gas used: 43%
- Gas price 63 gwei
- Web3 1.3.5

Should I just updated web3 or increase the gas? Is there an error I can capture for this event? I'm concerned that none of this matters as it's completing in a couple of minutes but web3 is reporting that it's going over the poll limit.